# How to dynmically add non-field data in a object?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, aura

I have a custom object Conversation, which has a field for Linked Object. That field contains the ID to an object (can be a multiple different types). I have a lightning component which requires that I fetch that record.

However, when I fetch the record, I need to also fetch custom information from the Linked Object. One example would be a Status (or whatever else I need) field from the linked object.

What I want to be able to do on the lightning component is put

```
{!v.conversation.Name}
{!v.conversation.LinkedStatus}
```

and see the value for the Name field of the conversation and the Status field of the linked object.

How can I achieve this?
Currently my APEX code is like this,

```
public static List<Conversation__c> getConversations()
    {
        List<Conversation__c> conversations = [SELECT Id, Name, FromNumber__c, ToNumber__c,  LinkedObjectID__c FROM Conversation__c WHERE Owner.Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
        return conversations;
    }
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this

```
public static List<Conversation__c> getConversations()
    {
        List<Conversation__c> conversations = [SELECT Id, Name, FromNumber__c, ToNumber__c,  LinkedObjectID__c FROM Conversation__c WHERE Owner.Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
        List<Conversation__c> editedConversations = new List<Conversation__c>();
        for (Conversation__c c : conversations)
        {
             Conversation__c temp = c;
             temp.LinkedStatus = Controller.getStatusOfObject(temp.LinkedObjectID__c);
             editedConversations.add(temp);
        }
        return editedConversations;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a wrapper class to achieve what you desire. It may not very scalable, though, as you need to add all the related properties you need.

```
public class ConversationWrapper
{
    public String linkedStatus { get; private set; }
    public Conversation__c record { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to reference either:

```
{!v.wrapper.record.Name}
{!v.wrapper.linkedStatus}
```

Comment: Would that be {!v.linked['Status']} or {!v.wrapper.linked['Status']} ?

Comment: @Jason Good catch. I was looking at how dynamic references work in Lightning for a refresher. I guess that part is less trivial than I assumed.

Comment: I guess for the scalability I can do something like changing the singular String variable to a Map of String values, so that I can just add and remove additional values as needed without making changes to my code.

Comment: True that. I haven't played with Lightning much so I wasn't sure if you could do dynamic reference with that either.